# Splitting lines and assigning two new values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, splitting, attribute-assistant

It is my understanding that when a line is manually split using the split tool in ArcGIS 10, the geoprocessing follows a create and copy format, meaning that one new feature is created, while the other retains all of the values of the original line segment.  My question is, is it possible to set up the behavior so that when a split is performed, a delete and two creates is executed.

I am working with a sewer dataset and utilitizing the attribute assistant add-in provided by ESRI.  I have a rule set up to generate a new facility id upon creation of a new main.  This works fine for one half of the split line, but since the other half is not considered a "new" line, it retains the facility id of the original segment.  I'm hoping there's a way to modify the split tool to create two new, unique lines upon split.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a bespoke customisation. An ArcGIS developer could do this, create a new button that splits a line by deleting the existing one and replacing it with 2 new lines. You can't change the behaviour on an existing tool you would have to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

if you work with geodatabase, you can set a domain for your field of interest. Using the domain, you can define merge and split rules. One of the rules is to use a default value which can in turn help to identify your "new" features.

Comment: That would work in theory, however, the field of interest is the unique facility id field, so I don't think I could populate that utilizing a domain, as it is auto-generated when a new feature is created via the attribute assistant add-in.